# R - Group by, then iterate through group and extract original column values

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataframe (df):

```
ID1 | ID2 |  V1  |  V2 |  V3
A   | B   | var1 | foo |  1   
C   | D   | var2 | bar |  2
E   | F   | var3 | foo |  3
G   | F   | var3 | foo |  3
H   | I   | var4 | zap |  2
...
```

ID1 and ID2 contain overlapping values, as it's a long format version of an upper matrix triangle with identical comparsions (eg A, A) removed and some additional metadata (V1,V2,V3) added.

The above must be grouped by V1, V2 & V3, and the final output is to be a list of IDs (ID1 and ID2 contain overlapping variables) that make up each group (with each list being a seperate file).

So far, I've grouped the variables but stuck on how to go on about iterating through each of dplyr's groups and obtaining the values for each.

A pseudocode of what I have in mind is below:

```
# Group
cluster <- df %>% group_by(V1,V2,V3) 

[?] # loop through each group in cluster
    
    [?] # get group values as x, y and z
    
    # Get IDs into lists and merge
    ID1 <- df %>% filter(V1 == x, V2 ==y, V3 == z) %>%
           pull(ID1)

    ID2 <- df %>% filter(V1 == x, V2 ==y, V3 == z) %>%
           pull(ID2)

    merged <- c(ID1,ID2) 
   
    merged_unique <- unique(unlist(merged))

    # Print out to file
    fileConn <- file(paste(X ,Y, Z,"txt", sep="."))
    writeLines(merged_unique, fileConn)
    close(fileConn)
```

I would like my final output to be:

- file var1.foo.1.txt :

```
A
B
```

- file var2.bar.2.txt :

```
C
D
```

- file var3.foo.3.txt :

```
E
F
G
```

- file var4.zap.2.txt :

```
H
I
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating your "data":

```
df <- data.frame("ID1" = c("A","B","C","E","G","H"), "ID2" = c("B","B","D","Fe","Fe","I"), "V1" = c("var1","var1","var2","var3","var3","var4"),"V2" = c("foo","foo","bar","foo","foo","zed"), "V3" = c(1,1,2,3,3,2))
```

Clustering the data and getting the unique clusters:

```
library(dplyr)
df_clust <- df %>% group_by(V1,V2,V3) 
df_tally <- df_clust %>% tally()
```

Looping through, assuming only two ID columns and 3 feature columns, and printing each result to a new file:

```
for (i in c(1:nrow(df_tally))){
    pull1 <- df %>% filter(V1 == unlist(df_tally[i,1]), V2 == unlist(df_tally[i,2]), V3 == unlist(df_tally[i,3])) %>% pull(ID1)
    pull2 <- df %>% filter(V1 == unlist(df_tally[i,1]), V2 == unlist(df_tally[i,2]), V3 == unlist(df_tally[i,3])) %>% pull(ID2)
    mergeID <- c(type.convert(pull1,as.is = TRUE),type.convert(pull2,as.is = TRUE))
    mergeID <- unique(mergeID)

    filename <- paste("TEST_",i, ".txt", sep="")
    fileConn<-file(filename)
    writeLines(mergeID, fileConn)
    close(fileConn)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the expected output. Hope the code below could help a bit

```
lapply(
  split(
    df[c("ID1", "ID2")],
    with(df, do.call(paste, list(V1, V2, V3)))
  ),
  function(v) unique(unlist(v))
)
```

which gives

```
$`var1 foo 1`
[1] "A" "B"

$`var2 bar 2`
[1] "C" "D"

$`var3 foo 3`
[1] "E" "G" "F"

$`var4 zap 2`
[1] "H" "I"
```

---

If you want to save all the groups into different `*.txt` files, you can try the code below

```
lst <- lapply(
  split(
    df[c("ID1", "ID2")],
    with(df, do.call(paste, list(V1, V2, V3,sep = "_")))
  ),
  function(v) unique(unlist(v))
)

sapply(seq_along(lst),function(k) writeLines(lst[[k]],paste0(names(lst[k]),".txt")))
```

Comment: Apologies for the confusuon on the outout. I've updated the question to include it.
Your suggestion is a great help, as it ets the correct output of IDs. However, do you know if it's possible to redirect it to text files (one per group)? My original dataset has about 225 groups so manually making the files myself is not ideal...

Comment: @Sleepy No worries. It seems I saw your response late and you already got what you want. Anyway, here is my version. Please check my update.